# The sum of the factors of 9!

Tags: factorial

The sum of the factors of 9! which are odd and of the form 3m+2(m is a natural number) is equal to

$(A)40\hspace{1 cm} (B)42\hspace{1 cm}(C)46\hspace{1cm}(D)52$

I could not identify factors,i think they will be lot many.Can someone assist me in solving this question?

Comment: I suggest you try somewhat harder to find a factor. To start with some small odd numbers is the form of $3m+2$, for example 5, 11 and 17, 23, 29 and 35.

Comment: what kind of factors do you mean, prime factors?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, No sir,not prime,any factors.

Comment: In the Hot Questions list, this question title just looks like you're very excited about summing the factors of 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible numbers are $5,11,17,23,29,35$. So, we have at least $5+35=40$. From the given options, the answer is $(A)$.

Comment: How do $11,17,23,29$ enter here?

Comment: @DanielFischer Numbers that have the form $3m+2$ and are odd.

Comment: @wythagoras But they should be divisors of $9!$. (Otherwise, why stop at $35$?)

Comment: Because they can only have one factor 5 and one factor 7 and no factors 3 because they are $3m+2$. Since they are odd, no factors 2. So it can't be larger than 35.

Comment: @Daniel: 35 **is** a factor of 9!. What I can't understand then is, how can the answer be **any** of the choices given ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, sure, $5\cdot 7 \mid 9!$, nobody here said anything else. Since $5$ and $35$ are the _only_ odd divisors of the form $3m+2$ that $9!$ has, the answer is $5 + 35$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You are right. I admit that my solution is saying that the only correct option is $(A)$. (And I thought this solution is ok in this situation.)

Comment: @mathlove Sure it's okay. I just wonder why you listed $11,17,23,29$ (but not $41,47,53,\dotsc$), since those don't divide $9!$. If you didn't have a particular reason, that's also fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Just because I noticed first that $5$ and $35$ are what we want, and saw the options, then I wrote my answer in that way.

Comment: @mathlove So if I understand correctly, you noted that the only relevant prime factors are $5$ and $7$, so we have an upper bound of $5\cdot 7$, and then listed all odd numbers $\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ up to and including that limit? Makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @mathlove: 40 ans is ok, but I suggest you should remove the terms that are **not** factors, and also remove **at least** 40

Answer (score 4):

Notice, $$9!=1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times 5\times 6\times 7\times 8\times 9$$$$=362880=2^7\times 3^4\times5\times 7$$
total number of odd factors $$=1\times5\times 2\times 2=40$$

But, the odd factors of form $(3m+2)$ are only two which can be found by putting $m=1$ & $m=11$ which are $3\times 1+2=5$ & $3\times 11+2=35$

Hence the sum of the odd factors of form $(3m+2)$
$$=5+35=40$$
Option (A) is correct.

Comment: Total number of odd factors = 1X 5 X 2 X 2 = 40 . It is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

$9!$ = $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8 \times 9$.  Of all the odd factors, only $5$ is of the form $3m + 2$. We can have $5$, and the only possible number to combine it is $7$ to give $35$ which is also of the form $3m + 2$. So these are the only 2 factors and their sum is $40$

Answer (score 2):

The factors that you are looking for are not divisible by 2 (because they are odd) and not divisible by 3 (because they are divisible by 3).

We have 9! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 x 9.

If we remove the factors 2 and 3, then all that is left is 5 x 7, and the only factors that are odd and not divisible by 3 are 1, 5, 7 and 35. Of these, only 5 and 7 are of the form 3n + 2. So the answer is 5 + 35 = 40.

If we asked about 10!, the same argument would leave us with 5 x 7 x 5, and the six factors, 1, 5, 7, 35, 25, 175. The additional factors 25 and 175 are both not of the form 3n + 2, so the final answer is again 40. Same for 7! and 8!.